# Как упростить выражение схемой Горнера?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, численные-методы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дано действительные числа x, y. Не пользуясь никакими другими арифметическими операциями, кроме умножения, сложения и вычитания, вычислить 5x^2y^2-3xy^2-17x^2y-2y^2+5xy+2x^2-4x+11y+7. Разрешается использовать не более восьми умножений и восьми сложений и вычитаний. Запрещается использование циклов и т.д. только линейное решение.

Не могу понять как упростить выражение схемой Горнера, именно с этим нужна помощь.

Comment: А c++-то откуда тут в тэгах, если это домашка по математике?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да все довольно просто, можно записать как

```
7 + (11 - 2*y)*y + x*(-4 + (5 - 3*y)*y + x*(2 + y*(-17 + 5*y)))
```

Ровно восемь умножений...

В код сами запишете? :)

Да, если `+(-17)` не рассматривается как одна операция сложения с числом `-17`, можно переписать как

```
7 + (11 - 2*y)*y + x*((5 - 3*y)*y - 4 + x*(2 + y*(5*y - 17)))
```